# Simple Distributed Erlang

Tags: erlang, distributed

I've got a simple module:

```
-module(dist).
-compile([add/3]).
add(From,X,Y) ->
    From ! X+Y.
```

And I'm starting two nodes.

One with

```
erl -sname foo
```

and another with

```
erl -sname bar
```

On the bar node I'm doing:

```
> c(dist).
{ok,dist}
> self().
<0.37.0>
> spawn('foo@unknown-00-23-6c-83-af-bd', dist, add, [self(), 3, 5]).
```

But the reponse I get is:

```
Error in process <0.48.0> on node 'foo@unknown-00-23-6c-83-af-bd' with exit value: {undef,[{dist,add,[<8965.37.0>,3,5]}]}
```

What does this error mean? I wondered if it meant that my foo node doesn't have this module defined? I didn't think it needed it, but the problem wasn't fixed by compiling dist in the foo node so I guess this isn't the problem.

Comment: Or use -compile(export_all). (Only during early development)

Comment: It seems like I still have to compile the dist module in both nodes. Is this how its supposed to work?

Comment: Are both nodes running on the same machine in the same working dir? If not, the second VM must have access to the beam file in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Export the add/3.  Instead of a compile option.

```
-export([add/3]).
```

Answer (score 0):

if in the first node you use nl(module) then the beam of that module will be loaded to all connected nodes