# Connecting to Nodes from scripts?

Tags: distribution, distributed

I am trying to test a system by calling a function I have written, which is in a script and is compiled on the Erlang shell (on windows).

The function connects to other nodes (which are running).

I am getting a problem stating that "Can not start erlang:apply,[......" and I think this is because I have not started the shell to act as a distributed node.

Could someone please advise what I need to do to be able to run a script from the shell, which messages other Nodes?

Comment: Here is a somewhat similar question with a simple example of calling functions on other nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199823/simple-distributed-erlang. If you need more help, please provide the code that you are trying to run.

Answer (score 3):

To start erlang distribution from an escript, you either need to pass the `-name Name` argument as a hot comment `%%! -name Name` in your escript, or you need to start distribution manually. I wrote an example for Erlang Factory 2011 (talk here -- http://www.erlang-factory.com/conference/SFBay2011/speakers/GeoffCant ).

I also have a link to [example code to start erlang distribution in an escript](https://github.com/archaelus/egc_examples/blob/master/hi_jack) from the [github repo](https://github.com/archaelus/egc_examples) I used in the talk.

It boils down to:

```
net_kernel:start([Name, longnames]),
erlang:set_cookie(Name, list_to_atom(Cookie)).
```

Comment: I may have misread your question - I thought you were talking about escript, not the erlang shell. This code will work in either however.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two things potentially wrong,

One, you simply are not set up as a node. On windows, you can fix this by passing "*-node NodeName*" into werl in a similar fashion to Unix, e.g:

```
$ erl -name zephmatic
(zephmatic@kerneltrap)1> node().
'zephmatic@kerneltrap'
```

If you've already set up the node name (just to be sure run node(). and erlang:get_cookie() in Erl!), I'm guessing it's the the actual node messaging semantics in erlang you're having trouble with -- This is an understandably broad topic and the entire Erlang language is almost wholly focused on solving the puzzle of correct messaging primitives. The canonical OTP reference is [Distributed Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html), but a humorous and (in my opinion) excellent introduction to the topic is [Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/).

If it's helpful to your immediate needs, here's some sample code for manipulating gen_server behavior that I've tested, feel free to invoke it, connect to it, and get high quality distributed programming for less (For a unlimited time only)!

Best of luck, and don't take over the world too quickly when you have the power of a billion machines at your disposal!

```
-module(communicate).
-author('Zephyr Pellerin').

-behavior(gen_server).

-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-export([start/0, grab/2, lookup/1, return/1]).

%%% The reason I declare all of these is to make calling
%%% namespaced functions easier, i.e, simply calling start(). 
%%% rather than gen_server:start_link()
start() ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).
grab(Which, Element) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {grab, Which, Element}). 
lookup(Element) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {lookup, Element}).
return(Element) -> 
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {return, Element}).

% The init method is a "callback" (Whatever that designation may imply)
% that occurs when another client connects
init([]) ->
    Resource = dict:new(),
    {ok, Resource}.

%%% The Generic server specifies that handling calls happens
%%% through handle_call, which would have thought!
%%% If you're not very experienced with Erlang, this below might seem
%%% strange to you -- it's just different ways to handle 
%%% input given differing "types" (Not a real thing in Erl). 

% This function simply looks to see if an element from
% a "Resource" is in use, if not it tells the other node
% that it is locked, or returns it if not.
handle_call({grab, Which, Element}, _From, Resource) ->
    Response = case dict:is_key(Element, Resource) of
        true ->
            NewResource = Resource,
            {locked, Element};
        false ->
            NewResource = dict:append(Element, Which, Resource),
            ok
    end,
    {reply, Response, NewResource};

% This function checks for the existence of an element 
handle_call({lookup, Element}, _From, Resource) ->
    Response = case dict:is_key(Element, Resource) of
        true ->
            {which, lists:nth(1, dict:fetch(Element, Resource))};
        false ->
            {not_locked, Element}
    end,
    {reply, Response, Resource};

% This uses scary language to annihilate an element! 
handle_call({annihilate, Element}, _From, Resource) ->
    NewResource = dict:erase(Element, Resource),
    {reply, ok, NewResource};

% These are simply functions that must be defined according to gen_server
% its not so special.
handle_call(_Message, _From, Resource) ->
    {reply, error, Resource}.
handle_cast(_Message, Resource) -> 
    {noreply, Resource}.
handle_info(_Message, Resource) ->
    {noreply, Resource}.

% You need to have a method that knows when to fold em' if someone requests termination

terminate(_Reason, _Resource) ->
    ok.

% While not *strictly* nessasary, this is a cool method that allows you to inject code
code_change(_OldVersion, Resource, _Extra) -> 
    {ok, Resource}.
```